# Когда я хочу включить Unity Ads мне выдаёт ошибку :

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

```
Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found.
  at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExtractZip (System.String zipFile, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] extractFilenames, System.String outputDirectory, System.Boolean update) [0x00141] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0 
  at Google.GradleWrapper.Extract (Google.Logger logger) [0x0003e] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.GradleResolution (System.String destinationDirectory, System.String androidSdkPath, System.Boolean logErrorOnMissingArtifacts, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action`1[T] resolutionComplete) [0x0007a] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.DoResolutionUnsafe (System.String destinationDirectory, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action resolutionComplete) [0x000bb] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<DoResolution>b__0 () [0x00001] in <48abf529805a49c69e88ffb3f8b573e9>:0 
  at Google.RunOnMainThread.ExecuteNext () [0x00047] in <ac8e755fbc27434ebdaf117e2c7041d9>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext ()
Google.RunOnMainThread/<>c:<ExecuteAll>b__24_0 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run (System.Action,bool)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:DoResolution (string,bool,System.Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe (System.Action`1<bool>,bool,bool,bool)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver/<>c__DisplayClass102_0:<ScheduleResolve>b__1 ()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob ()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ScheduleResolve (bool,bool,System.Action`1<bool>,bool)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve (System.Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver/<>c:<ScheduleAutoResolve>b__78_1 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs ()
Google.RunOnMainThread/<>c:<ExecuteAll>b__24_0 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О, я просто установил новейшую версию юнити